# Filter of dplyr (with any of rows)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm new in the R world, these days I have problem with the filter function of dplyr.I have a df and a I need to filter the values greater than a number, but in some rows I have multiples values (separeted by ; ).
For example I have this df

```
ID   value1    value2
1    1;0;3.4    4
2    3          5
3    0.5;2;1.3  0
4    5;0.1      3
```

My filter is if one or more in value1 is greater or equal than 3. I use the function filter  of dplyr because I need realize others filters to the df. This is my code.

```
filt <- df %>% filter(any(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(value1,';',fixed=TRUE))) >=3))
```

But in this case the any function considers all the values of the df (not by row, as I thought), so, I obtein all df and that is not correct.

I need obtain row with id 1,2 and 4 for this example.

I think I should check by row and separate by ; , but I don't know how to do this with the filter function of dplyr.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Use `rowwise()` before the filter so the processing happens row by row, or, better yet, transform your data to a more "tidy" format using something like `tidyr::separate_rows`

Comment: Oh thanks!! I really really like this solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to split the 'value1' with `separate_rows` from `tidyr`, grouped by 'ID', `filter` groups having `any` element in 'value1' greater than or equal to 3, then `summarise` the columns by `paste`ing and getting the `first` element of 'value2'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    separate_rows(value1, sep = ";", convert = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(any(value1 >=3)) %>%
    summarise(value1 = str_c(value1, collapse=";"), value2 = first(value2))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     ID value1  value2
#  <int> <chr>    <int>
#1     1 1;0;3.4      4
#2     2 3            5
#3     4 5;0.1        3
```

---

Or using `map` with `strsplit`

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   filter(map_lgl(strsplit(value1, ";"), ~ any(as.numeric(.x) >=3)))
#   ID  value1 value2
#1  1 1;0;3.4      4
#2  2       3      5
#3  4   5;0.1      3
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, value1 = c("1;0;3.4", "3", "0.5;2;1.3", 
"5;0.1"), value2 = c(4L, 5L, 0L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```